# Looking for an understanding of Toroidal Moments

Tags: neutrinos, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_moment) page is not so enlightening

Apparantly the Neutrino, if it is a Dirac particle, has a Toroidal Moment. Does this mean the Dirac neutrino would interact electromagnetically as well as weakly?

Comment: Here is an entire book about toroidal moments: https://www.amazon.com/Toroidal-Multipole-Moments-Classical-Electrodynamics/dp/3658125489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Although neutrinos have no charge and therefore don’t interact directly with an electromagnetic field, in principle they do so indirectly through electrons and W bosons. See the relevant one-loop Feynman diagrams here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0206083.pdf

As far as I am aware, this electromagnetic interaction is too small to be measured.

Comment: Does the toroidal moment derive from these e W loop interactions? Or is it different?

Comment: According to the paper, these e-W loop interactions cause the neutrino to have a toroidal moment.